# Codename One - MediaPlayer permissions on Android

Tags: codenameone

My app show an intro background video (in a `BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_TOTAL_BELOW`) with code similiar to this one:

```
MediaPlayer introVideo = new MediaPlayer();
introVideoMP4 = "/intro-landscape.mp4";
InputStream videoInputStream = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), introVideoMP4);
introVideo.setDataSource(videoInputStream, "video/mp4", () -> {
     introVideo.getMedia().setTime(0);
     introVideo.getMedia().play();
});
```

The problem is that the app asks for this permission at the first runtime:
`"Allow appname to access photo, media, and files on your device?"`

Is it possible to avoid this request in this case, that is to play a file that is stored in the /src folder of the app? I dislike this request.

*For example, the Android app "Lifesum" (available in the Play Store) shows an intro background video at the first start without asking any permission,* **so I suppose that it should be possible to avoid this permission request** (any workaround?).

Comment: That permission request isn't related to that code as far as I can tell. You can test it by commenting out that code and seeing if the permission is still there. If it does trigger that permission that sounds like a regression.

Comment: I confirm that the permission request is related to that code.

Comment: I filed this issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2385

Comment: Looking into it. I suggest placing code in the issue as stackoverflow deletes questions sometimes...

Comment: Ok, I've just seen that you fixed this issue. Thank you. I clicked on "Update Project Build" and I sent a new Android build, but your fix is not applied. Have I to do something else to update the CN1 lib?

Comment: This will be in the build servers on Friday, core changes/fixes propagate into the weekly releases.